# How do I properly redirect url using php header function

Tags: php, sweetalert2

I am trying to redirect url to the parent file after a delete command has been exicuted from a child file
and show sweetalert2 success message on the parent file.
It work perfectly on my local machine but not working on the online server.
Please I need your favor.

This goes to my child file(**actions.php**)

```
  <a href="actions.php?delid=<?php echo ($row->employee_id); ?>"class="del_btn" title="click to block">
      <i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
  </a>
```

Then I am getting the Id **actions.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['delid'])) {
    $rid = intval($_GET['delid']);
    $sql = "update employees set status='0' where employee_id='$rid'";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':rid', $rid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    header('location: employees.php?delid=1');
  }
```

Comment: is there **any** output at all within `actions.php` before you call `header`?

Comment: Your SQL is wide open to SQL Injection - **Never** use content supplied by the user directly in the sql statement, instead you should **always** use a `prepared statement` with properly bound placeholders/variables

Comment: Your placeholders and bound parameters do not match - you are using `?` as the placeholder in the sql and then attempting to bind `:rid`

Comment: The actions.php file contain a lot of update and insert queries that all has output to diffrent files.

Comment: If you have any output before calling `header` you can encounter errors which might manifest themselves such that the script appears to not work - error reporting whilst developing this might help if that is the case

Comment: Please sir how do I share my actions.php file with you so that you can polish things up for me. I am new and I have no experience.

Answer (score 0):

Your `prepared statement` was fundamentally flawed and open to sql injection. You need to use either the `?` style of placeholder in the sql or named placeholders, such as `:rid` - you cannot mix the two types and hope that it will work. You have also cast the supplied variable as an `int` so it might make sense to use the PDO constant for int datatypes instead of strings.

```
if( isset( $_GET['delid'] ) ) {

    $rid = intval($_GET['delid']);
    $sql = 'update `employees` set `status`='0' where employee_id=:rid';
    
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':rid', $rid, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->execute();
    
    exit( header('Location: employees.php?delid=1') );
}
```

Using the question mark placeholder syntax you would do something like this:

```
if( isset( $_GET['delid'] ) ) {

    $rid = intval($_GET['delid']);
    $sql = 'update `employees` set `status`='0' where employee_id=?';
    
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bindParam( 1, $rid, PDO::PARAM_STR ); #  note here the use of 1 to indicate the first placeholder
    $stmt->execute();
    
    exit( header('Location: employees.php?delid=1') );
}
```

Comment: Please can you give me code with the ? style, I have tried the : style and it did not work. I am new in programming, I dont know the diffrence of those styles.